# Execute method when Android app process is finished

Tags: android, kill

I'm working on an Android app and I need to know when the OS killed the process, so I can make a HTTP request to my server. I've tried to start a service and put the request in the onDestroy() method, but the service only stops when I kill it manualy (with START_STICKY). With I use START_NOT_STICKY, the service ends with the app, but it does not execute the onDestroy() method.

My manifest looks like this:

```
<service
android:name=".CheckSessionEndService"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="false" >
</service>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Android app process" and "when the OS killed the process"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the process is killed it's really gone. You can't execute anything anymore. onDestroy() is called after your service is stopped, either by stopService() or stopSelf() (and the Service isn't bound), but that does not necessarily mean the process has been killed. If you're concerned about the user swiping your app from recents you could try

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent)

or

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ServiceInfo.html#FLAG_STOP_WITH_TASK

Comment: Yeah, that's what I feared. So the closest that I can get to that is using the onTaskRemoved() method?

Comment: I've never used it myself, but looks like it's your best option. It is only available on api levels 14+ though. Of course it doesn't help you at all if your process is killed for some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

OnDestroy() not always have called, if system kills the app. You must call your method in several places - in both onDestroy and onStop() and also in [onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()). But onStop() have more chances to be called, if system need to free memmory, rather then onDestroy().

Comment: There is no onStop() on a Service